# What to claim on w-4 for a second job?

Tags: united-states, withholding, form-w-4

I am a single mom with 2 kids and work #1 job that pays 23,000 per year and I have just picked up a #2 job that will pay 21,000 per year. I don't want to owe taxes at the end of the year. What should I claim on my w-4 for the 2nd job?

Answer (score 4):

The W-4 should have a worksheet for multiple jobs, so you could start with that.  Then after you get a paycheck, see how much tax will be taken out for the year and compare it to an estimate of your tax liability for the year.

According to [this basic tax estimator](http://www.calcxml.com/calculators/federal-income-tax-calculator), with a $46,000 income and 3 exemptions, your annual tax liability would be about $2,600. (this assumes no other income and no itemized deductions for mortgage interest, charities, medical expenses, etc.)  If you don't want to be surprised with a tax bill at the end of the year you could be conservative and withhold enough to cover that with some extra cushion.

Comment: I'm getting less liability. Just checking, did you use head of household?

Comment: I may have used Single, but the principle is the same - if you want to avoid a tax bill make sure you withhold enough to cover your expected tax bill for the _year_.  It may take a few paychecks and tweaking of the exemptions to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule of thumb on a second job is to take zero exemptions.  So if you follow the worksheet, it might tell you to mark in 4 or 3.  However, you already marked those on your first job.  So put in 0 for the second job.

You can double check this with the [tax estimator](http://www.calcxml.com/calculators/federal-income-tax-calculator) posted in the [other answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/75879/25282).  $44,000 income, 3 exemptions, 2 dependent children as head of household gave $720 as your total liability.  Putting in $23,000 income with the 3 exemptions and 2 dependent children gave zero liability for the first job.  Putting in $21,000 with zero exemptions gives $1170 from the second job.  So if their withholding matches that, you'd get a refund of around $450.

Another way of looking at it is that you need to withhold about $14 a week.  If you're withholding more than that between the two jobs, you could cut back.  If you're withholding less, then you should add more if you don't want to owe anything.

I think that you have extra exemptions after your first job.  So two exemptions on your second job will probably produce the correct result.  Then you wouldn't get much of a refund.  However, as I said, you should verify this on your actual paychecks.

The safest way is to do the zero exemptions on the second job's W-4.  Worst case, you overwithold and get a refund.  You'll lose out on a bit of interest income, but interest rates suck anyway.  Losing $5 for peace of mind may be worth it.

Comment: "You'll lose out on a bit of interest income" or ability to pay off debt, set up emergency fund, etc.  Not refuting your answer but overwithholding can cause other issues.